Flatpickr from react-flatpickr
While using the flatpickr in the popover from the material/tailwind-react library when the i select the data from the flatpickr popup is closing  i try to stop the propagation using e.stopPropagation and many things but nothing working help me resolve this issue
 <ThemeProvider value={customTheme}>
            <Popover
              open={openPopover}
              dismiss={"outsidePressEvent"}
              handler={() => setOpenPopover(!openPopover)}
              placement='bottom'
              className=''>
              <PopoverHandler>
                <button
                  style={{
                    background:
                      "linear-gradient(90deg, #9FB947 -15.87%, #739500 100%)",
                  }}
                  className='text-white outline-none  rounded-md text-center justify-center  flex flex-row gap-[0.5rem] px-[2rem] py-[0.5rem] '>
                  Filter
                </button>
              </PopoverHandler>
              <PopoverContent className='max-w-[500px]'>
                <FilterComponent />
              </PopoverContent>
            </Popover>
          </ThemeProvider>

i try to stop the propagation using e.stopPropagation and many things but nothing working help me resolve this issue

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
